# Access codeigniter controller from command line

Tags: codeigniter, php

I'm playing around with CI around PHP CLI.

I'm now able to access the whole CI structure via a Global variable $CI (followed the tutorial here http://codeigniter.com/wiki/dip_into_CI/)

```
$CI = new $class();
$CI -> load->view ('header');
```

Now works good, but I don't know how to access a controller thru the $CI variable.

Let's say I have a controller called main(); i'd like to be able to do something like :

```
$CI->main->myfunction($params);
```

Must be real simple but can't figure out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's all possible but a little crazy. Just use CodeIgniter Reactor. Controllers can respond to command line perfectly.

https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor

php index.php controller method param1 param2

Works with routing and everything.

Comment: Interesting; what's the difference between the 'standard' CI and the reactor ? Can't see much a difference

Comment: Reactor is the community branch which will become the new suggested download. It progresses faster and accepts community contributions to the code so bugs are fixed quicker.

Comment: Interesting. Any chance of this new method of command line access  working with Modular Extensions? I have it working properly in a fresh CI install but as soon as I try to access a route in my app which uses MX I just get the main /index html returned via command line

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. It works with MX and the "regular" CI that you download from codeigniter.com.